# Predictions with ARIMA (python statsmodels)

Tags: python, time-series, prediction, statsmodels

I have some time series data which contains some seasonal trends and I want to use an ARIMA model to predict how this series will behave in the future.

In order to predict how my variable of interest (`log_var`) will behave I have taken a weekly, monthly and annual difference and then used these as the input to an ARIMA model.

Below is an example.

```
exog = np.column_stack([df_arima['log_var_diff_wk'], 
                        df_arima['log_var_diff_mth'], 
                        df_arima['log_var_diff_yr']]) 

model = ARIMA(df_arima['log_var'], exog = exog, order=(1,0,1)) 
results_ARIMA = model.fit()
```

I am doing this for several different data sources and in all of them I see great results, in the sense that if I plot `log_var` against `results_ARIMA.fittedvalues` for the training data then it matches very well (I tune p and q for each data source separately, but d is always 0 given that I have already taken the difference myself).

However, I then want to check what the predictions look like, and in order to do this I redfine `exog` to just be the 'test' dataset. For example, if I train the original ARIMA model on 2014-01-01 to 2016-01-01, the 'test' set would just be 2016-01-01 onwards.

My approach has worked well for some data sources (in the sense that I plot the forecast against the known values and the trends look sensible) but badly for others, although they are all the same 'kind' of data and they have just been taken from different geographical locations. In some of the locations it completely fails to catch obvious seasonal trends that occur again and again in the training data on the same dates each year. The ARIMA model always fits the training data well, it just seems that in some cases the predictions are completely useless.

I am now wondering if I am actually following the correct procedure to predict values from the ARIMA model. My approach is basically:

```
exog = np.column_stack([df_arima_predict['log_val_diff_wk'], 
                        df_arima_predict['log_val_diff_mth'], 
                        df_arima_predict['log_val_diff_yr']])

arima_predict = results_ARIMA.predict(start=training_cut_date, end = '2017-01-01', dynamic = False, exog = exog)
```

Is this the correct way to go about making predictions with ARIMA?

If so, is there a way I can try to understand why the predictions look very good in some datasets and terrible in others, when the ARIMA model seems to fit the training data just as well in both cases?

Comment: Without much understanding on what ARIMA does, it might be that you are just overfitting your model. Overfitting is a very common problem in machine learning, which happens when you train your model to match perfectly your training data, but then it is useless on predicting the testing set (seems to be what is happening). If it is the problem (hard to say), you can try playing with the parameters until the fit on the training set is good enough but not perfect, ARIMA might hen generalize better to the test dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem atm which I have not entirely figured out yet. It seems including multiple seasonal terms in python is still a bit tricky. R does seem to have this capacity, [see here](https://blog.pivotal.io/data-science-pivotal/products/forecasting-time-series-data-with-multiple-seasonal-periods). So, one suggestion I can give you is to try this with the more sophisticated functionality R provides for now (although that could require a large investment of time if you are not familiar with R yet).

Looking at your approach for modeling the seasonal patterns, taking the nth order difference scores does not give you seasonal constants, but rather some representation of the difference between the time points that you designate as seasonally related. If those differences are small, correcting for them might not have much impact on your modeling results. In such cases, model prediction might turn out fairly well. Conversely, if the differences are big, including them can easily distort prediction results. This could explain the variation you are seeing in your modeling results. Conceptually, then, what you'd want to do instead is represent the constants over time.

In the blog post referenced above, the author advocates the use of Fourier series to model the variance within each time period. Both the NumPy and SciPy packages offer routines for calculating the fast Fourier transform. However, as a non-mathematician I found it difficult to ascertain that the fast Fourier transform yielded the appropriate numbers.

In the end I opted to use the Welch signal decomposition form SciPy's signal module. What this does is return a spectral density analysis of your time series, from which you can deduce signal strength at various frequencies in your time series.

If you identify the peaks in the spectral density analysis which correspond to the seasonal frequencies you are trying to account for in your time series, you can use their frequencies and amplitudes to construct sine waves representing the seasonal variations. You can then include these in your ARIMA as exogenous variables, much like the Fourier terms in the blog post.

This is about as far as I have gotten myself at this point - right now I am trying to figure out whether I can get the statsmodels ARIMA process to use these sine waves, which specify a seasonal trend, as exogenous variables in my model (the documentation specifies they should not represent trends but hey, a guy can dream, right?) edit: [This](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/) blog post by Rob Hyneman is also highly relevant, and explains some of the rationale behind including Fourier terms.

Sorry I'm not able to give you a solution that's proven to be effective within Python, but I hope this gives you some new ideas to control for that pesky seasonal variance.

TL;DR:

- It seems python is not very well suited to handle multiple seasonal terms right now, R might be a better solution (see reference);
- Using difference scores to account for seasonal trends seems not to capture the constant variance associated with the recurrence of the season;
- One way to do this in python could be to use Fourier series representing seasonal trends (also see reference), which can be obtained using, among other ways, a Welch signal decomposition. How to use these as exogenous variables in an ARIMA to good effect is an open question, though.

Best of luck,

Evert

p.s.: I'll update if I find a way to get this to work in Python